# DataContext and ContentControl

Tags: wpf

I always thought ControlControl must be listening to DataContextChanged and then setting `this.Content = this.DataContext` but now I managed to reflect the source code of ContentControl and I cant find the spot where does the Content get set.

I am talking about having a ContentControl inside the Template without setting Content like this `Content = {TemplateBinding prop}`.

Does anybody know how ContentControl works exactly? How does Content gets set internally?

It seems to me right now all I knew about ContentControl is trash hehe.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: If users must down vote questions or answers, can they please let the user know why, so that they may learn from their mistakes? I personally see no reason why this question has received two down votes.

Comment: i second @Sheridan on this

Comment: I have not downvoted, but thought about it. There are ten million posts about this subject - this shows not prior research what-so-ever...

Comment: Can somebody of you admins remove this question I would like to post a new one with better description and code example

Answer (score 3):

Adding to what @nit said, the content of a `ContentControl` has no internal self connections. Instead, it is common for them to be used inside other controls where their `Content` property is data bound to a property of the parent control... this *may* make it appear to work automatically:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridCellWrapTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Border Name="DataGridCellBorder">
        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In this case, the `ContentControl.Content` property is internally data bound to the `DataGridCell.Content` property. This means that whatever is set as the `Content` of the `DataGridCell` will be displayed in this `ContentControl`.

You can think of a `ContentControl` as being a 'holder of data', although this is not necessarily data bound data. We are (mostly) used to creating `DataTemplate`s to define what the data objects in our collection controls should look like. You can think of it like there being a `ContentControl` for each item in the collection.

Following on from this, it means that if can use a `DataTemplate` to define what each collection item will look like, we can also use one to define what the single item in a `ContentControl` will look like:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeDataObject}" 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeDataTemplateToDefineWhatTheDataLooksLike}" />
```

Of course, if we have declared a `DataTemplate` of the relevant type without setting the `x:Key` property, then we can omit the setting of the `ContentTemplate` property. The `ContentControl` is therefore useful for displaying one item from a collection using the same `DataTempate`.

To address your comment, that would be because of the 'limited default `Style`' that a `ContentControl` uses. For more information, I would advise you to look at the [ContentControl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) page on MSDN... from that page:

> A ContentControl has a limited default style. If you want to enhance the appearance of the control, you can create a new DataTemplate.

Comment: I am not setting content anywhere. Read my question again please. I am using the ContentControl inside my template and the content property is not data bound but it works. How so?

Comment: This is a great answer _again_ from you and makes the question viable to me.

Comment: Remove the question please I would like to post a new one with code showing exactly what my problem is

Comment: Either add an UPDATE >>> section to your question here with your new information, or add a new one, optionally providing a link to this one.

Answer (score 2):

`Content` of the `ContentControl` is always set externally either statically like

```
<ContentControl Content="MyContent"/>
```

or by binding

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Name}"/>
```

In later case, content is searched within `DataContext` if not set explicitly. Hence if Content is bound within DataContext then DataContext change will be reflected, otherwise not.

> Setting DataContext does not mean the Content will be set
>   automatically

Comment: Read my question again. I am not setting content anywhere. The content control itself is just part of template but it works. How so?